# In SharePoint online, is it possible to dynamically feed the name of the user loading the page to the Organizational Chart web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, search, modern-experience, administration

I am the SharePoint Online administrator for my employer. My management wants me to produce or find a web part similar to the out-of-the-box Organizational Chart web part, but they want the web part to display the organization of the employee who loaded the SharePoint page, not the organization of an employee who was specified at design time.

I know how to use the Organizational Chart web part (and the People web part), but I have not been able to configure it to load the organization dynamically.

I asked AI, but AI did not have an answer that solves my problem.

Comment: Update: I have also (recently) used the PnP Framework Search Box, Search Results and Search Filters web parts to build a searchable, filterable FAQ list. I tinkered around with those web parts a bit hoping to produce the functionality my management is looking for, but I don't think PnP Framework contains the solution I need.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, SharePoint online out of the box Organizational Chart web part and the People web part does not support dynamically showing the information of currently logged in user.

You will have to use the custom SharePoint framework (SPFx) web part for you requirements.

Check below SPFx samples available on GitHub which will help you to get started with:

1. [Modern Organization Chart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-modern-organization-chart) - This web part show organization chart for current user
2. [Organisation Chart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-organisationchart)
3. [Organization Chart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-organization-chart)
4. [Tree Organization](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-tree-orgchart)
5. [Organization Chart using VueJS](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/vue-js-org-chart)

You can also enhance these web parts on your own by downloading the code of these free SPFx samples developed by community members and made available in PnP GitHub repository.

**Related documentations**

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Comment: Thank you @Ganesh! I am investigating now